# Rails: incomplete paths for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I had a site with devise. I installed ActiveAdmin and removed it.
Now my **complete** list of paths is

```
rake routes
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                root        /                                      {:controller=>"codes", :action=>"list"}
                            /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))
```

There is no paths like `new_user_registration_path` or `edit_user_registration_path`, that described in [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template).
How can I to restore that links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you configure your User model (or whatever model you are using devise with) with the correct options. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-models

You are probably missing:

```
devise :registerable
```